# Inputting a decimal using a button(Calculator

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with my decimal being input using my javascript. i have a function checking to see if the output is Not a number If so i would like for it to output a decimal instead of NaN

I have tried adding another if else statement like so.

```
var operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
for(var i =0;i<operator.length;i++){
    operator[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(this.id=="clear"){
            printHistory("");
            printOutput("");
        }
        else if(this.id=="backspace"){
            var output=reverseNumberFormat(getOutput()).toString();
            if(output){//if output has a value
                output= output.substr(0,output.length-1);
                printOutput(output);
            }
        }
        else{
            var output=getOutput();
            var history=getHistory();
            if(output===""&&history!==""){
                if(isNaN(history[history.length-1])){
                    history= history.substr(0,history.length-1);
                }
            }
            if(output!=="" || history!==""){
                output= output===""?output:reverseNumberFormat(output);
                history=history+output;
                if(this.id=="="){
                    var result=eval(history);
                    printOutput(result);
                    printHistory("");
                }
                else{
                    history=history+this.id;
                    printHistory(history);
                    printOutput("");
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for(var i =0;i<number.length;i++){
    number[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        var output=reverseNumberFormat(getOutput());
        if(output!=NaN){ //if output is a number
            output=output+this.id;
            printOutput(output);
        } if (output=NaN){
            printOutput('.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: share your html part of the code as well..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) which is a built-in function. And just to ensure that is definitely not an `Nan`, do a [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), which will ensure that it is really checking a `float` and not a `string`.

```
isNaN(parseFloat(output))
```